# Processing.js Clear Screen to Transparent

Tags: html5-canvas, processing, processing.js

I have a Processing.js sketch that must be transparent. I figured out how to set the background to be transparent by default, however, when I draw on the sketch I seemed to have permanently marked the canvas.

Is it possible to clear the canvas and set it back to transparent using Processing.js?

If not, is `context.clearRect(params)` fast enough/ a suitable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the first two results for googling "Processing.js transparent background":

http://processingjs.org/reference/transparent/

http://processingjs.org/reference/background_/

(Even without google, the reference should be your first stop for questions like this.)

Anyway, yes you can use a transparent background. Just use the `/* @pjs transparent="true"; */` directive at the top of your code to enable transparency, and then pass an alpha value into the `background()` function.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I assumed that it would overlay a completely transparent sheet over the background and achieve nothing.

Comment: @BenjaminSpiegel That's why it's always best to write a little example program to test your assumptions!